# How do I correctly utilize the IF and isblank function when trying to hardcode Formulas in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following hardcoded formula in VBA, which keeps giving me an error when I try to execute it. Is it the `""""` that is causing the syntax error?

```
IF(isnblank(VLOOKUP([@[Uid]],tblProjectPlan[[Uid]:[Adjusted Sart]],13,false)),"""",VLOOKUP([@[Uid]],tblProjectPlan[[Uid]:[Adjusted Start]],13,false))
```

Comment: `isnblank` isn't a built-in Excel function. Unless you've defined it yourself as a UDF, that will give you problems. Have you tried `NOT(ISBLANK(...))`?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. but even with ISBLANK or ISNA it gives me an error..

Comment: Double check the subexpression `VLOOKUP([@[Uid]],tblProjectPlan[[Uid]:[Adjusted Sart]],13,false)` either by stepping through the formula execution or executing that expression manually. Does it give you what you expect? Also, where/what is the exact error you are getting?